# C++ error that I do not understand: syntax missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++, class, identifier

```
class Dialogue
{
public:
    int id;
    int trigger;
    Question descendants[5]; // Max questions per dialogue
    string text;
};

class Question
{
public:
    int id;
    int descendant;
    int ancestor;
    string text;
};
```

When I try and build this, it says the following error for the Question descendants bit?:

> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'descendants' c:\users**\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\game\game\dialogue.h    8   1   Game Error  2   error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int   c:\users**\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\game\game\dialogue.h    8   1   Game

Comment: forward declaration? Swap order of class declaration

Comment: I'd say it's because `Question` is defined after `Dialogue`, but is used in the definition of `Dialogue`.

Comment: You are using `Question` before you have declared it as a class. In this case, you can just put `Question` above `Dialogue`, but sometimes you need a forward declaration [`class Question;`] to tell the compiler there is a class of that name.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can forward declare your classes.  This is handy when they both depend on each other:

`class Question;
class Dialogue;`

class Dialogue
{
public:
    int id;
    int trigger;
    Question descendants[5]; // Max questions per dialogue
    string text;
};

class Question
{
public:
    int id;
    int descendant;
    int ancestor;
    string text;
};

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the definitions around, so that `Question` is known to the compiler at the time you use it in the declaration of `Dialogue`.

This will compile:

```
class Question
{
public:
    int id;
    int descendant;
    int ancestor;
    string text;
};

class Dialogue
{
public:
    int id;
    int trigger;
    Question descendants[5]; // Max questions per dialogue
    string text;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of class Question should be first and then followed by class Dialogue.

```
class Question
{
public:
    int id;
    int descendant;
    int ancestor;
    string text;
};

class Dialogue
{
public:
    int id;
    int trigger;
    Question descendants[5]; // Max questions per dialogue
    string text;
};
```

Comment: Ah man, I didn't know you had to declare classes in order. Makes sense. Thanks. me and my noobness ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Swap order of class declaration:

```
class Question
{
public:
    int id;
    int descendant;
    int ancestor;
    string text;
};

class Dialogue
{
public:
    int id;
    int trigger;
    Question descendants[5]; // Max questions per dialogue
    string text;
};
```